# Why does categories array in function setupAndStart not printing anything to console?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a function called `setupAndStart()`. Within that function I am calling `getCategoryIds()` to get an array of category ids. Then, I am passing each element in the array to `getCategory(id)` to get an object and pushing the returned valued to categories array.
However, when I try to loop through the categories array and print each element I don't get any results.

```js
const URL = `https://jservice.io/api`;
const NUM_QUESTIONS = 5;
const NUM_CATEGORIES = 6;

// categories is the main data structure for the app; it looks like this:

//  [
//    { title: "Math",
//      clues: [
//        {question: "2+2", answer: 4, showing: null},
//        {question: "1+1", answer: 2, showing: null}
//        ...
//      ],
//    },
//    { title: "Literature",
//      clues: [
//        {question: "Hamlet Author", answer: "Shakespeare", showing: null},
//        {question: "Bell Jar Author", answer: "Plath", showing: null},
//        ...
//      ],
//    },
//    ...
//  ]

let categories = [];

/** Get NUM_CATEGORIES random category from API.
 *
 * Returns array of category ids
 */

async function getCategoryIds() {
  let response = await axios.get(`${URL}/categories`, {
    params: { count: "100", offset: 20 },
  });

  let randomCategory = _.sampleSize(response.data, NUM_CATEGORIES);
  let categoryIDs = randomCategory.map((item) => {
    return item.id;
  });

  return categoryIDs;
}

/** Return object with data about a category:
 *
 *  Returns { title: "Math", clues: clue-array }
 *
 * Where clue-array is:
 *   [
 *      {question: "Hamlet Author", answer: "Shakespeare", showing: null},
 *      {question: "Bell Jar Author", answer: "Plath", showing: null},
 *      ...
 *   ]
 */

async function getCategory(catId) {
  let response = await axios.get(`${URL}/clues`, {
    params: { category: catId },
  });

  let fiveClues = _.sampleSize(response.data, NUM_QUESTIONS);

  let questionAnswerArray = fiveClues.map((arr) => {
    return {
      question: arr.question,
      answer: arr.answer,
      showing: null,
    };
  });

  let titleClueObj = {
    title: fiveClues[0].category.title,
    clues: questionAnswerArray,
  };
  return titleClueObj;
}

/** Fill the HTML table#jeopardy with the categories & cells for questions.
 *
 * - The <thead> should be filled w/a <tr>, and a <td> for each category
 * - The <tbody> should be filled w/NUM_QUESTIONS_PER_CAT <tr>s,
 *   each with a question for each category in a <td>
 *   (initally, just show a "?" where the question/answer would go.)
 */

async function fillTable() {
  let catagoryRow = $("<tr>");
  $("thead").append(catagoryRow);

  for (let i = 0; i < NUM_CATEGORIES; i++) {
    $("<td>Cat</td>").appendTo(catagoryRow);
  }

  for (let y = 0; y < NUM_QUESTIONS; y++) {
    let questionRow = $("<tr>");
    $("tbody").append(questionRow);
    for (let x = 0; x < NUM_CATEGORIES; x++) {
      let question = $("<td>").text("?").attr("id", `${x}-${y}`);
      question.appendTo(questionRow);
    }
  }
}

/** Handle clicking on a clue: show the question or answer.
 *
 * Uses .showing property on clue to determine what to show:
 * - if currently null, show question & set .showing to "question"
 * - if currently "question", show answer & set .showing to "answer"
 * - if currently "answer", ignore click
 * */

function handleClick(evt) {}

/** Wipe the current Jeopardy board, show the loading spinner,
 * and update the button used to fetch data.
 */

function showLoadingView() {
  $("table").show();
  $(".start").show();
}

/** Remove the loading spinner and update the button used to fetch data. */

function hideLoadingView() {
  $("header").hide();
  $("#spin-container").hide();
}

/** Start game:
 *
 * - get random category Ids
 * - get data for each category
 * - create HTML table
 * */

async function setupAndStart() {
  let categoryIDs = await getCategoryIds();
  categoryIDs.forEach(async (id) => {
    let tempCategory = await getCategory(id);
    categories.push(tempCategory);
  });
  fillTable();
  for (let i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
    console.log(categories);
  }
}

/** On click of start / restart button, set up game. */

// TODO

/** On page load, add event handler for clicking clues */

// TODO

setupAndStart();
```

Comment: What step-by-step debugging have you done? Try to narrow down what function is causing the problem. For example: what are the values in each function as they're transformed, and do they match your expectation?

Comment: When I console.log(categories) it prints the object array, but when I use a loop to get each element printed I don't get anything printed. I think the problem could be how each object is pushed to the categories array.

Comment: Instead of using forEach loop in the setupAndStart() function, I used for loop and it is working now. I can print each element from the categories array onto the console.